# Need Current Location of User in Android , Not Last known location

Tags: android, location, currentlocation

I am developing an android application in which i want to get users current location when application start, But when i start my application it gives the last known location when it start first time, But i want the updated current location of the user as soon as possible on application start.

Please guide me about this.
Thanks

Comment: Well if it doesn't know where you are, it uses the last known location.

Comment: Is not there any way to get current location when application start 1st time OR application not proceed for any next activity until application get current location update, not last known location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LocationServices](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html). It containes all location strategies described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is not there any way to get current location when application start 1st time OR application not proceed for any next activity until application get current location update, not last known location.