# Android: Get current location instead of last known

Tags: android, location

**EDIT**: As Francky Vincent said, I see that price depending on distance is not advisable. I have 4 parts but only 3 are the prices depending heavily on the distance (and planning to change it later). But, I still need to get current location as I have 'x.x KM from you'.

---

A little bit of intro:

When I was around somewhere with low coverage, I open the Grab app and able to get my current location, even though will take too much time. My own app have no problem with location but at the same location, it will get the last known location - and I don't want that since one of my app feature is the price is according to the distance between current location and target.

For the codes, I just using the [examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java) provided for Fused Location by Google in Github and seems like it's not enough? My aim is to get current location instead of last known - just like the Grab app.

Is that possible using Fused Location? Or did the example provided can achieve what I want but I missed something important?

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441789/need-current-location-of-user-in-android-not-last-known-location) but still got clueless. Really new with this feature.

The strategies that I can come up is:

1. Start app
2. Check permission
3. Request permission
4. Get current location
5. Save the latitude and longitude in SharedPreference
6. Stop getting location

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You should not correlate money and gps location because anyone can manipulate their own gps location.

Comment: @FranckyVincent make sense. Thank you for that. I edited my question.

Comment: Requesting location updates will get you the current location.  It just won't do so immediately (getting the location takes time).  GetLastKnownLocation rarely works and should only be used as an optional optimization.

Comment: @GabeSechan so the difference that I got comparing between two apps is just a coincidence?